# counter increment and value storage on buttonclick

Tags: android, count, buttonclick

I'm creating voting application on android and extracting data from json file on recyclerview. After that on particular item click I'm opening an activity having some credentials and button for that participant. On that button click I want to get count increment by 1 and store the incremented count value in firebase.

Comment: Where is the code? What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0;
public void onclick(View v){
count++;
}
```